# archive one table date in another table with archive date in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i have one table test it has 10 column with 20 rows.

I need to move this data to archive_test table which has 11 column (10 same as test table plus one column is archive date).

when i tried to insert like below its shows error because number of column mismatch.

```
insert into archive_test
 select * from test;
```

Please suggest the better way to do this.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, obviously you need to supply values for all the columns, and although you can avoid doing so you should also explicitly state whic value is going to be inserted into which column. If you have an extra column in the target table you either:

1. Do not mention it
2. Specify a default value as part of its column definition in the table
3. Have a trigger to populate it
4. Specify a value for that column.

eg.

```
insert into table archive_test (col1, col2, col3 ... col11)
select col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       ...
       sysdate
from test;
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming that `archive_date` is the **last** column:

```
INSERT INTO archive_test
SELECT test.*, sysdate
FROM   test
```